# Problem while using WebKit browser's InvokeScriptMethod()

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, wpf, protovis

I am using WebKit browser control in my WPF application. I am using it because I want to rendered Protovis enabled HTML on it. Till this point I am successful. Now, I want to pass some parameters specially arrays of double, int and strings to one of the Java script method of the rendered page within the control. I tried InvokeScriptMethod() API from WebKit but it did not work for me if I want to pass parameter(s). Everything works well if I invoke the script method which doesn't take any parameter.

Can somebody help me? I am desperate for it.:)

Thanks,
Omkar

Comment: How is it not working? Is there an error message? Can you post the code fragment you are using to call the API?

Comment: Just to add few things, I got HRESULT as E_FAIL in my .net application when I tried to call that method. Following is the code

Comment: As requested by Lazarus, adding the my code below.

# Java Script code
function DisplayData(obj) 
{
            document.write(obj+" : ");
}

# C# code
browser.Document.InvokeScriptMethod("window.DisplayData", new object[]{"omky","sourabh"});

I always get "null" in java script.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Hello, Can anybody help me in above query?

Answer (score 1):

I get HRESULT as E_FAIL if I don't wait until the site is fully loaded.

You have to wait until this event:

```
private void webKitBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    object[] arr = {"some parameter"};
    String returned = webKitBrowser1.Document.InvokeScriptMethod("JavascriptFunctionName", arr) as String;
}
```

is fired. After that, everything worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use, 
webKitBrowser1.StringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("javascript:YourMethod();");